# Error In Omniauth with Google

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, oauth, oauth-2.0, omniauth

When I am connecting with google it gives us

```
OAuth2::Error ({"errors"=>[{"domain"=>"usageLimits", "reason"=>"accessNotConfigured", "message"=>"Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."}], "code"=>403, "message"=>"Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."}:
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
 }
}
):
```

Please someone help me

Comment: i think answer in your questions.

Comment: Sorry sir can u explain this I am not getting your point

Comment: in you log: `Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi My problem was resolved

When i enable the `google+ api` in Google Developers Console it's working fine.

Comment: what did it have to with `google+ api` in particular? You just connected via OAuth2, right? That didn't involve google+ api in any way. The thing is, I'm having the same error but I'm not working with google+ api.